# Google Map Api v2 Error

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

i am getting numm pointer exception on execution on following code in fragment.

```
 MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container1, mapFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
 mGoogleMap=mapFragment.getMap();
 mGoogleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().draggable(true).position(new LatLng(22.03, 72.56)).title("hello world").snippet("Ahmedabad").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.wifi)));
```

> 03-01 15:59:49.370: E/AndroidRuntime(12577): Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 03-01 15:59:49.370:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(12577):  at
>   com.tfick.fragment.PoiFragment.onCreateView(PoiFragment.java:64) 03-01
>   15:59:49.370: E/AndroidRuntime(12577):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
>   03-01 15:59:49.370: E/AndroidRuntime(12577):  at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
>   03-01 15:59:49.370: E/AndroidRuntime(12577):  at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635) 03-01
>   15:59:49.370: E/AndroidRuntime(12577):    at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1397)

Comment: Wrong code. What is PoiFragment? The problem is there.

Comment: poi fragment is the name of fragment class

Comment: when i remove last two line from the code it works just fine 
but when last two line is added it stop working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of the problem i found.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.tfick.android.R;

public class PoiFragment extends MapFragment {
    /*object of google map*/
    public GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    /* summy location*/
    private static final LatLng SYDNEY = new LatLng(23.03, 72.62);


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (getMap() != null) {
            Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Map ready for use!");

            mGoogleMap = getMap();

            /* cretaing custom camera position */

            CameraPosition mCameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(SYDNEY).bearing(0).tilt(30).build();
            Log.i("gmap", mGoogleMap.toString());

            /* setting custom camera position */

            mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory
                    .newCameraPosition(mCameraPosition));

            /* adding custom marker on the map. */
            mGoogleMap
                    .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .draggable(true)
                            .position(new LatLng(22.03, 72.56))
                            .title("hello world")
                            .snippet("Ahmedabad")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.wifi)));

            mGoogleMap
                    .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .draggable(true)
                            .position(new LatLng(23.03, 78.10))
                            .title("hello world")
                            .snippet("Baroda")
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                    .fromResource(R.drawable.wifi)));

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved problems . This is solution [Google Maps Android API v2 - Add a marker failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154906/google-maps-android-api-v2-add-a-marker-failed)

Comment: ya but what is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `getMap()` returns `null`. 
Possible solutions:

- Did you check via `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)` that the Google Play Service is available?
- The map may not have been initialized yet, try `getMap()` in a later point of the lifecycle, like `onResume()`

Comment: MapFragment mapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container1, mapFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();

this peace of code is working correct
but when i tro getmap() it will not do so .

Comment: Yes, that is because getMap() returns null. Did you try one of my propositions?