# Add marker to Google Maps standard app

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

From my app I'm calling Google Maps app (or other) using implicit intent:

```
    Uri location = Uri.parse(getResources().getString(R.string.latlng_map));
    Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, location);        
    try {
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mapIntent, "View on map ...")); ...
```

Is there a way to add Marker on it at the location point? Some kind of passing additional values like  putExtra()?
I was thinking why make new viewing map activity when there is an app doing the same (and better then I would make).

Comment: Refer this Post: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/15155074/3326331](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15155074/3326331)

Comment: @SagarPilkhwal this post is not relevant to OP's question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot add custom overlays/markers to **Google Maps application**. If you need to show something custom on map, it's better to handle maps yourself in your app (and then you can add whatever you want over it).

Comment: Yes, it seems I have to deal with API. Thanks